# sql update table from another table snappydata

Tags: sql, sql-update, snappydata

Hi I am using SnappyData's sql utility to update table my table from another table, say update `Table_A` with rows from `Table_B`.

```
Table_A(col_key, col_value) -- partitioned table with large number of rows 
Table_B(col_key, col_value) -- small batch update in this table
```

Ideally a [MERGE](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1704/using-merge-in-sql-server-to-insert-update-and-delete-at-the-same-time/) would be ideal (update if there is a match, or insert if the row with the key does not exists in `Table_A`)

But MERGE is not supported in SnappyData (or Gemfire), thus I am planning to insert first with an outer join to handle new col_key rows, then an update to update values in `Table_A`
where the same `col_key` also appears in `Table_B`.

However it seems that the "update ... set ... from ... " is also not supported in [Gemfire](http://gemfirexd.docs.pivotal.io/1.3.1/userguide/reference/language_ref/ref-update.html)

So is there a way to implement the "update .. set .. from .." in SnappyData sql statements? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `PUT INTO` when using SQL or you can do the same using the [Snappy Spark extension APIs](http://snappydatainc.github.io/snappydata/apidocs/#org.apache.spark.sql.SnappySession) too.

Answer (score 1):

I just found that GemFire actually use a "[PUT INTO](http://gemfirexd.docs.pivotal.io/docs-gemfirexd/reference/language_ref/put-into.html)" statement to kind of support the "INSERT or UPDATE" (MERGE) function by other DBMSes.

Basically first retrieve the 'old' values from my `TABLE_A` where the `col_key` exists in , add them to `TABLE_B`, and use "PUT INTO" to put those rows in `Table_B` to `Table_A` and it's done!